# Postgres: Self-Referencing N:N Getting Data with Function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return the `ingredient_title` of `component_id`, but keep getting the title of `ingredient_id` instead and can't seem to figure out the logic.

Returning array because there can be multiple components of ingredients that have the same limiting quantity.

Junction Table of `ingredients_components` `ingredient_id` and `component_id` are both foreign keys that point to `ingredients.ingredient_id` and both are primary keys of this junction table

Recreate Example

```sql
CREATE TABLE ingredients (
  ingredient_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ingredient_title VARCHAR(255),
  ingredient_quantity NUMERIC(8,2) DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO ingredients(ingredient_title, ingredient_quantity)
VALUES
('Frosting', 5.00),
('Egg', 13.00),
('Butter', 8.00);

CREATE TABLE ingredients_components (
  ingredient_id INT REFERENCES ingredients (ingredient_id),
  component_id INT REFERENCES ingredients (ingredient_id),
  required_component_quantity NUMERIC(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT ingredient_component PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_id, component_id)
);

INSERT INTO ingredients_components(ingredient_id, component_id, required_component_quantity)
VALUES
(1, 2, 2.00),
(1, 3, 4.00);
```

My Function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_part_limiting_components_title(arg_ingredient_id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR[] AS
$$
    SELECT array_agg(ingredient_title)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ingredient_title,
            FLOOR(ingredient_quantity/required_component_quantity) AS limiting_component_quantity
        FROM ingredients
            INNER JOIN ingredients_components
            ON ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients_components.ingredient_id
        WHERE ingredients_components.ingredient_id = arg_ingredient_id
            AND FLOOR(ingredient_quantity/required_component_quantity) =
            (
                SELECT
                FLOOR(ingredient_quantity/required_component_quantity) AS limiting_component_quantity
                FROM ingredients
                    INNER JOIN ingredients_components
                    ON ingredients.ingredient_id = ingredients.ingredient_id
                WHERE ingredients.ingredient_id = arg_ingredient_id
                ORDER BY limiting_component_quantity ASC
                LIMIT 1
            )
        ORDER BY limiting_component_quantity ASC
    ) AS limiting_component
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;

--RUN Function
SELECT fn_part_limiting_components_title(1);
```

Comment: A function declared as `returns table (...)` would probably be more appropriate. But it's unclear to me, what result you are actually expecting. Are you trying to recursively go through all components of an ingredient and return the one with the smallest limiting quantity?

Comment: Trying to return an array of components where it has the smallest limiting quantity for a specific ingredient (thus argument of ingredient_id). Can be multiple components where they are smallest limiting quantity (thus an array)

Comment: So which ingredient(s) do you expect when passing `ingredient_id = 1`?

Comment: It’s suppose to be {Butter}.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be simplified by using a window function to calculate the smallest limiting quantity:
select ingredient_id, ingredient_title, limiting_component_quantity
from (
select i.*,
FLOOR(ingredient_quantity/required_component_quantity) AS limiting_component_quantity,
dense_rank() over (order by FLOOR(ingredient_quantity/required_component_quantity)) as rnk
from ingredients i
join ingredients_components ic on i.ingredient_id = ic.component_id
where ic.ingredient_id = 1
) t
where rnk = 1;

I would put this into a set-returning function:

```
create function  fn_part_limiting_components_title(arg_ingredient_id integer)
  returns table (ingredient_id integer, 
                 ingredient_title text, 
                 limiting_component_quantity numeric)
as
$$
 select ingredient_id, ingredient_title, limiting_component_quantity
 from (
    select i.*,
           FLOOR(ingredient_quantity/required_component_quantity) AS limiting_component_quantity,
           dense_rank() over (order by FLOOR(ingredient_quantity/required_component_quantity)) as rnk
    from ingredients i
      join ingredients_components ic on i.ingredient_id = ic.component_id
    where ic.ingredient_id = arg_ingredient_id
 ) t
 where rnk = 1;
$$
language sql;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from fn_part_limiting_components_title(1);
```

Comment: Yeah, I am not familiar with window functions or set-returning function. So I will have to look into that.